# Cannot make a . desktop file works

Tags: .desktop

I want to create a desktop shortcut to a sh script, wha I did make a terminal blink and launch nothing :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Stable diffusion
Exec=sh ~/AI/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh
```

What is wrong ?

EDIT I managed to screenshot the terminal as it was closing :
[image]

It seems the shortcut try to execute the script on the desktop, is there a way to tell it the context is the sh folder ?

Bonus question : Where is the doc for .desktop shortcuts ? How is it called ?

Comment: Add a line of `Version=1.0` right below the line of `[Desktop Entry]`.  You might also need to change the `~/AI/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh` to `/home/username/AI/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh`.  Also, if the `.sh` file can be run in the background, you usually don't need the `Terminal=true`.  You can try making that `Terminal=false`

Comment: `[[: not found` is likely because you are trying to run a **bash** script with **sh** - best practice is to make sure the script itself is executable and then let its shebang line determine the appropriate interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use bash syntax on the `EXEC=` line, replace "`~/`" with "`$HOME/`", or with the actual expanded value.
2. Don't use `sh`, it's a link to `/bin/dash`, a less featureful shell. Change the first line of `$HOME/AI/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh` to  "`#!/bin/bash`" (or write a wrapper script), make it executable with `chmod +x $HOME/AI/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh`, and use "`EXEC=$HOME/AI/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.sh`

Comment: I agree with 1, but 2 is essentially irrelevant. 1) There is no reason why a user should not be allowed to invoke /bin/sh (or /bin/dash). Of course, the script must be compliant to that more minimal shell, which is used by default on Ubuntu, Bash is used only in an interactive terminals. 2) starting a script using `sh` instead of making it executable is a perfectly valid approach.